# How to hide 'Bearer token' in Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, flutter-web

I'm using an api in flutter web and I noticed that when I call DevTools(F12) Chrome the token is visible. Is there any way this can be hidden?

It's listed on devtools(F12) Chrome:

```
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
authorization: Bearer 'abcdefg' 
content-type: application/json;
```

Code example:

```
var response = await http.post(Uri.parse('.../V1/customers'),
          body: convert.jsonEncode(
            {
              "customer": {
                "email": email,
                "firstname": firstName,
                "lastname": lastName,
                "taxvat": document,
              },
              "password": password
            },
          ),
          headers: {
            HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
            HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer token',
          });
```

Comment: This is more of a web problem than a flutter web problem. As far as I know, it simply can't be hidden. Why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: For security. I don't want users to see my api token

Comment: I think you might be confusing API token with auth bearer token. API tokens live on your server and should not be accessed by users. Auth bearer tokens are owned by users to authenticate their identity.